# How do I display input column table rows through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to write a program that will give my Table element appropriate column and rows I was able to do the rows part but I get stuck on columns, what is my code not working?

```
<body>
    <table>
        <script>
            var c = parseInt(prompt("Enter column ")) // 10
            var r = parseInt(prompt("Enter column ")) // 10

            while (0 < c) {
                c--;
                document.write("<td style></td>")
            }

            var r = parseInt(prompt("Enter row "))
            while (0 < r) {
                r--;
                document.write("<tr></tr>")
            }
        </script>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns are defined by the cells - which are nested in the rows. Also, You would need to run through that more than once (for each row), so you can't spend the variable.

Try the code as following:

```
<script>
   var c = parseInt(prompt("Enter column ")) // 10
   var r = parseInt(prompt("Enter row ")) // 10
   var cTmp = c;

   while(0<r){
      r--;
      cTmp = c;
      document.write("<tr>")
      while(0<cTmp){
          cTmp--; 
          document.write("<td style></td>")
      }
      document.write("</tr>")
   }
</script>
```

**Edit**

You should note that html tables are not defined by rows and columns, rather by rows, and the cells within each row. In essence, this creates columns, but we redefine them for each row.

Comment: Did you run this code, it spins and hangs.  The `while` method in JavaScript, for all the times I've tried to use it, is not good on browsers and I assume it's better to just use `for` instead.

Comment: Should be fine now, when switching the variables I left out the one in the condition

Comment: Thanks but I'm little confused about how this work, in which line of code does it specify to print out number of rows(or columns) which user prompted?

Comment: The outer loop does the rows. The inner loop does the columns (which are actually the cells in each row)

Comment: Ah thanks makes it more clear, one more question why do we need extra variable cTmp?

Comment: Because we do the cells (aka columns) for each row, if we decrease the original down to 0 it'll still be zero the next time around and no cells will be generated for the next row. Using an extra variable allows us to reinitiate it to the the original column value each time through the loop

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you can't treat Javascript like you'd do with PHP. You are risking that the tags are not written at the position you want, but at the start of the document.

I'd recommend you give a read to the "[Manipulating DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp)" over w3schools

Now, to answer you question, the easiest way to achieve this, is using jquery, that way you don't need to deal with several way to manipulate the DOM and make it crossbrowser

```js
var c = parseInt(prompt("Columns"));
var r = parseInt(prompt("Rows"));

for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    var newRow = $("<tr></tr>");
    for (var j = 0; j < c; j++) {
        newRow.append("<td></td>");
    }
    $("#customTable").append(newRow);
}
```

```css
table, tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="customTable" width="100%"></table>
```

Now, if you need vanilla javascript (i.e. no Jquery)

```js
var c = parseInt(prompt("Columns"));
var r = parseInt(prompt("Rows"));
var table = document.getElementById("customTable");

for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var j = 0; j < c; j++) {
        var newColumn = document.createElement("td");
        newRow.appendChild(newColumn);
    }
    table.appendChild(newRow);
}
```

```css
table, tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="customTable" width="100%"></table>
```