# While Loop: Generated table rows and column inconsistency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, html-table

Please explain why the code I borrowed from another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611733/how-do-i-display-inputted-column-table-rows-through-javascript#33611733) question produces inconsistent results.  The program accepts 2 inputs, rows and columns. It *should* then generate a table with the exact amount of table rows and table columns that was input.  However, the first row seems to multiply out the cells  and decrease each row until the final row actually renders what every other row should be.

Also, I noticed that when I move line 25 inside of the inner `while` loop, that a table that is akin to a pyramid is generated (which is cool) but I cannot explain what it is doing.

`$("<tr  class='tableRow'>").appendTo('table#container');`

So with that said, please help me generate a table that will evenly render rows and columns when the input is equal.

Note: Entering 1 for rows and 1 for columns does return the intended result, but that is the only scenario where it "works". Entering 2 for rows and 2 for columns, produces unintended results.

[Sandbox Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/41h846s2/5/)

```js
//Table Generator
var c = 10; //parseInt(prompt("Enter column "), 10);
var r = 10; //parseInt(prompt("Enter row "), 10);
var cTmp = c;
var rTmp = r;

function rowLoop() {
  $('tr.tableRow').each(function(index) {
    var trFound = $("tr.tableRow:eq(" + index + ")");
    var rowNum = parseInt(($("tr.tableRow:eq(" + index + ")").index()), 10);
    var tdAdd = "<td>test</td>";
    if ($(this).index() === rowNum) {
      trFound.append(tdAdd);
      console.log("Add a TD");
      console.log(rowNum + "=" + $(this).index());
      console.log(rowNum + "=" + $(this).index());
    } else {
      console.log(rowNum + "<>" + $(this).index());
      console.log(rowNum + "<>" + $(this).index());
    }
  });
}
while (0 < rTmp) {
  cTmp = c;
  $("<tr  class='tableRow'>").appendTo('table#container');
  while (0 < cTmp) {
    rowLoop();
    cTmp--;
  }
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML + "</tr>";
  rTmp--;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px #ACE;
}
tr {
  height: 15px;
}
td {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='container'></table>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on how it handles `$("<tr  class='tableRow'>").appendTo('table#container');`, at this point you've added a broken html tag with no closing tag to the table. The browser probably completes this for you, perhaps create a empty HTML var and append to it then add it at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## jQuery Plugin

You can skip the loop altogether and use a range-map. You can actually define an array using:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(n)) // Where n is an integer greater than 0
```

You can then map each item in the array to either a function or the current index in the map function.

```
map(function(_, idx) {
    // Return the current index in the map's "loop" callback.
    if (val == null) return idx;
    // Execute the value as a function; pass index as 1st param.
    if (isFunction(val)) return val.call(null, idx);
    // Return the value as an (assumed) scalar value.
    return val;
});
```

Here is a jQuery plugin to generate rows and columns using the explained trick above to generate an array at a desired size with an option default value.

```js
//Table Generator
(function($) {
  $.fn.generateTable = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
      rows: 0,
      cols: 0,
      fill: function(row, col) {
        return row + 'x' + col;
      }
    };
    var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);
    function fillArray(n, val) {
      return Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map(function(_, idx) {
        return val == null ? idx : isFunction(val) ? val.call(null, idx) : val;
      });
    }
    function isFunction(value) {
      return typeof value == 'function';
    }
    return $(this).append(fillArray(opts.rows, function(row) {
      return $('<tr>', {
        class: 'tableRow'
      }).append(fillArray(opts.cols, function(col) {
        return $('<td>', {
          text: isFunction(opts.fill) ? opts.fill.call(null, row, col) : opts.fill
        });
      }));
    }));
  };
}(jQuery));

$(function() {
  $('#container').generateTable({
    rows: 10, //parseInt(prompt("Enter row count"), 10)
    cols: 10, //parseInt(prompt("Enter column count"), 10)
    fill: 'test'
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px #ACE;
}
tr {
  height: 15px;
}
td {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='container'></table>
```

---

## Stages of Development

Below, you will see how each successive block of code has evolved from its predecessor.

#### I. Vanilla JavaScript translated to jQuery

```js
//Table Generator
var cols = 10; //parseInt(prompt("Enter column "), 10);
var rows = 10; //parseInt(prompt("Enter row "), 10);

generateTable('#container', rows, cols, 'test');

function generateTable(selector, rows, cols, fill) {
  var $el = $(selector)
  createRows($el, rows, cols, fill);
}

function createRows($table, rows, cols, fill) {
  for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    $table.append(createRow(row, cols, fill));
  }
}

function createRow(row, cols, fill) {
  var $row = $('<tr>', {
    class: 'tableRow'
  });

  createCols($row, row, cols, fill);

  return $row;
}

function createCols($row, row, cols, fill) {
  for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
    $row.append(createCol(row, col, fill));
  }
}

function createCol(row, col, fill) {
  return $('<td>', {
    text: fill || row + 'x' + col
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px #ACE;
}
tr {
  height: 15px;
}
td {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='container'></table>
```

#### II. Simple jQuery Plugin

```js
//Table Generator
(function($) {
  $.fn.generateTable = function(options) {
    var $table = $(this);
    _createRows($table, options.rows, options.cols, options.fill);
  };
  _createRows = function($table, rows, cols, fill) {
    for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
      $table.append(_createRow(row, cols, fill));
    }
  };
  _createRow = function(row, cols, fill) {
    var $row = $('<tr>', {
      class: 'tableRow'
    });

    _createCols($row, row, cols, fill);

    return $row;
  };
  _createCols = function($row, row, cols, fill) {
    for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
      $row.append(_createCol(row, col, fill));
    }
  };
  _createCol = function(row, col, fill) {
    return $('<td>', {
      text: fill || row + 'x' + col
    });
  };
}(jQuery));

var cols = 10; //parseInt(prompt("Enter column "), 10);
var rows = 10; //parseInt(prompt("Enter row "), 10);

$(function() {
  $('#container').generateTable({
    rows: rows,
    cols: cols,
    fill: 'test'
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px #ACE;
}
tr {
  height: 15px;
}
td {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='container'></table>
```

#### III. Advanced jQuery Plugin

```js
//Table Generator
(function($) {
  $.fn.generateTable = function(options) {
    $(this).append(_fillArray(options.rows, function(row) {
      return $('<tr>', {
        class: 'tableRow'
      }).append(_fillArray(options.cols, function(col) {
        return $('<td>', {
          text: options.fill || row + 'x' + col
        });
      }));
    }));
  };

  function _fillArray(n, defaultValue) {
    return Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map(function(val, idx) {
      if (defaultValue === undefined) return idx;
      if (typeof defaultValue == 'function') return defaultValue.call(null, idx);
      return defaultValue;
    });
  }
}(jQuery));

var colCount = 10; //parseInt(prompt("Enter column "), 10);
var rowCount = 10; //parseInt(prompt("Enter row "), 10);

$(function() {
  $('#container').generateTable({
    rows: rowCount,
    cols: colCount,
    fill: 'test'
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px #ACE;
}
tr {
  height: 15px;
}
td {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='container'></table>
```

Comment: Solid advanced IIFE that can be used on a plug and play basis.  Still, that vanilla JS answer was superb (but so simple).  Thanks for taking the time to go in-depth on the explaining.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a `while-loop` why don't you just use a simple *nested* `for-loop`? This will make this task much easier to read and comprehend.

```js
//Table Generator
var cols = 10; //parseInt(prompt("Enter column "), 10);
var rows = 10; //parseInt(prompt("Enter row "), 10);

generateTable('container', rows, cols, 'test');

function generateTable(id, rows, cols, fill) {
  var elTable = document.getElementById(id);
  createRows(elTable, rows, cols, fill);
}

function createRows(elTable, rows, cols, fill) {
  for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++) {    
    elTable.appendChild(createRow(row, cols, fill));
  }
}

function createRow(row, cols, fill) {
  var elRow = document.createElement('tr');
  elRow.className = 'tableRow';
  createCols(elRow, row, cols, fill);
  return elRow;
}

function createCols(elRow, row, cols, fill) {
  for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
    elRow.appendChild(createCol(row, col, fill));
  }
}

function createCol(row, col, fill) {
  var elCol = document.createElement('td');
  elCol.innerHTML = fill || row + 'x' + col;
  return elCol;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px #ACE;
}
tr {
  height: 15px;
}
td {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='container'></table>
```

Comment: Good separation of function here.

Comment: This is elegantly written vanilla JS.  Could you perhaps make it a little more simple for me to understand by using jQuery (in a separate answer).  I will have to study how you assign variables and declare things in one single line.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem likely stems from the fact that within each `rowLoop()` execution, you are using this as selector for iteration:

```
$('tr.tableRow')
```

This will grab all rows that are currently in DOM for iteration, not just the current row you are working on.

A few options:

- Build a single row object with X number of columns first, then make clones of it and append to table for Y number of rows.
- Build Y empty TR's first, then iterate over each TR, appending X TD's.

Comment: Hi Mike, I thought that by tying the index strictly to the each table row via `index()` method would prevent that.  Could you elaborate on why that did not work?